# Prove $30|(a^3b-ab^3) $

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that if three distinct integers are chosen at random then there will exists two among them, say $a$ and $b$ such that $30|(a^3 b-ab^3)$

Comment: You don't even need to assume that the three integers are distinct, because $30\mid 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$a^3b-ab^3=ab(a^2-b^2)=ab(a-b)(a+b)$$

Hints: check that no matter what the parity of $\;a,b\;$ is, the above product is always even and thus divisible by two.

Also, no matter what $\;a,\,b\,$ are, the product is always divisible by $\;3\;$ .

I'll leave to you the funniest part: to prove the product **of two of the three different integers chosen** is always divisible by $\;5\;$ (*not necessarily a given pair* $\;a,b\;$ !) . Observe that you can reduce this to the case where the three different integers are different $\;\pmod5\;$ , otherwise we're done (why?) .

Answer (score 1):

By Fermat's little theorem (or simply by direct calculation), $x^2\equiv x$ mod $2$ and $x^3\equiv x$ mod $3$ for *any* integer $x$.  It follows that

$$a^3b\equiv ab\equiv ab^3\mod 6$$

for any pair of integers $a,b$, hence $6$ divides $a^3b-ab^3$ for any pair.  It remains to show that $5$ divides $a^3b-ab^3=ab(a^2-b^2)$ for at least one of the three pairs.  But there are only three squares mod $5$, namely $0$, $1$, and $-1$.  So given three integers, either two of their squares, say $a^2$ and $b^2$ belong to the same residue class, in which case $5$ divides $a^2-b^2$, or one of the three squares, say $a^2$ is $0$ mod $5$, in which case $5$ divides $a$ (and you can let $b$ be either of the other two numbers).  In either case $5$ divides $ab(a^2-b^2)=a^3b-ab^3$ for the chosen pair, and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

1) **Divisibility by $5$**.

Let $\{a,b,c\}$ the three numbers reduced modulo $5$. If one of them is $0$ or two of them are equal we clearly have
$$ab(a+b)(a-b)\equiv 0\pmod 5$$
So be all the three, $a,b,c$ distinct and non-zero modulo $5$ so we have
$$\{a,b,c\}=\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\{1,3,4\},\{2,3,4\}$$
In the four cases we clearly have two of the (class) numbers have sum $0$ modulo $5$ (because of $2+3=1+4$) so $ab(a+b)(a-b)\equiv 0\pmod 5$.

Thus the expression is for two of the three integers divisible by $5$.

2) **Divisibility by $3$ and by $2$**.

The same method but easier than for divisibility by $5$ can be used for divisibility by $3$ and by $2$.

Thus the divisibility by $30=2\cdot3\cdot5$ of the expression for two of the three numbers..